# Start TeXstudio portable in multiple instances

Tags: texstudio, parameters, portability

I use TeXstudio portable and want to use it in multiple instances when double clicking a `.tex` or `.txss` file. The necessary starting parameter is described [here](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38), but I do not know how to use it. Do you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using linux? Open the prompt command window and type `texstudio file --start-always` where `file` is the name of you file to open.

Comment: Sorry for that missing information. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I have now filed https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/354 "GUI configuration for --start-always" for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume this is Windows. There, you have to change the *file association* for `.txss` and `.tex` files so that this `--start-always` parameter is used, like

```
"c:\path\to\texstudio.exe" --start-always "%1"
```

. The answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7) on SuperUser.SX explains in detail how to apply these settings.

Comment: Thanks! I use the answer from kyrisu and create a `.bat` file to change the extension association.

Comment: @Dirk would you mind sharing this file for direct reuse?

Comment: @RobertPollak This is quite a long time ago. Currently, I don't use the portable version any more as well as the `bat` file. Sorry.