# How can I see two tex-files in TeXstudio simultaneously?

Tags: texstudio, linux

I would like to open two `.tex` files in TeXstudio side by side. I can image two possible answers, but I did not figure out how to exactly do it:

1. Find a split screen button in TeXstudio (like in kate for example).
2. Open a second instance of TeXstudio . When I do this in Linux, the old TeXstudio window gets focused but no new Window appears.

What can I do?

Comment: Sort of same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/start-texstudio-portable-in-multiple-instances

Comment: There's a couple of open feature requests about split screen functionality: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/631/ http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/69/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Split screen is supported in TeXstudio since update hg 5927 (0ce664cc1a7e) in 2016-03.

You can split the screen by right clicking on the file tabs and selecting the appropriate options.

Editing multiple files with split screen view

[image: Two Tex Files!]

Comment: How did you make it to display the same file side-by-side?

Comment: @Christoph90 I am interested too in knowing the method.

Comment: i use: TeXstudio 2.11.2 and i cannot unsplit it, but have to reopen editor. horror

Answer (score 19):

On windows I managed to have two TeXstudio sessions in two different processes by modifying the program shortcut (I keep mine on the taskbar) with what Tim Hoffmann said: you have to right click on the shortcut, go to properties and then on the shortcut tab you have to add `--start-always` in the Target field.

The shortcut's Target field should look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe" --start-always
```

Note that there is a space between the `"` and `--`! That is important!

Now all you have to do is start the program twice and work on two different files. I suspect that working on the same file twice will create problems with the auxiliary files so one should be a bit careful. I work on two different TeX files in the same directory but they have different names so there is no overlap.

I have no idea how to do this in Linux but I suspect something similar should be possible!

Comment: been looking for this for ages. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

Split screen is now supported since 2.11.0. Use the options from the context menu of the tab.

<s>Split screen is currently not supported.</s>

<s>You can use the option `--start-always` to open multiple instances of TXS. See [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38). Note: all instances save their settings to the same location when exiting, so the settings of the last close instance will persist.</s>

Comment: A bit late, but I will give it a try. Can you please tell where exactly do I have to add this command?

Comment: @user2536125 I've added an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495768/132895) that tells how to do it since no one is willing to share it.

Answer (score 7):

None of the answer *actually* tell what to do:

View a file in parallel:
right click on tab -> **"move to other view"**

Change the split style:
right click on tab -> **"split horizontally/vertically"**

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've misread that. Thanks for the correction, I've removed the comments.

Comment: In my version 4.4.2 there is only **split horizontally**! How can I **split vertically**

Answer (score 5):

In Linux:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/texstudio.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
nano ~/.local/share/applications/texstudio.desktop
```

change `Exec=texstudio %F` to `Exec=texstudio --start-always %F`, save with `CTRL+o`, exit with `CTRL+x`.

Background: By using a user-level copy of the system-wide .desktop file, we make sure our change is not overwritten on updates. The one in `/usr` does not need to be deleted because user-level `.desktop` files have a higher priority.

Comment: I know this is two years old, but thanks so much! This was exactly the fix I was looking for. Except I use Exec=texstudio --start-always %F. This variant gives me better behavior when opening files with spaces in the name. Using Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @KyleFerendo Then you may want to check this out: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/964/

Comment: @KyleFerendo s version worked for me, while the original answer didn't.

Comment: Great suggestion. Works flawlessly and needs no administrator privileges.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux:
Open a terminal and type: texstudio --start-always