# TeXstudio split screen

Tags: texstudio, editors

Is it possible to open **two documents at the same time** and display them **side by side**?

- e.g. vertical split: the first document on the left and the second document on the right of the screen

This issue is discussed in this older post [How can I see two tex-files in TeXstudio simultaneously?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186758/how-can-i-see-two-tex-files-in-texstudio-simultaneously) but the answer is unfortunately not clear to me.

Can you please explain it **step-by-step**?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to see the source code of both documents or do you want multiple pdfs?

Comment: I tried the accepted answer and my TexStudio crashed. Finally I decided to just open the second tex file in a different editor (Visual Studio Code).

Comment: 4 years have passed by,and this is still a shortcoming of this otherwise very good LaTeX editor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short

Yes, it **is possible to split the editor** window into horizontal or vertical panes by opening two files then clicking on the tabs

#### Step-by-step

1. Open at least two files (see note 1) --> or step 2 is greyed out.
2. Right-click on tab you want to `Move to split view`
   [image: (Picture in preparation)]
3. Select "move to other view"
4. If you want to split the screen horizontally, see note 2
   [image]

#### Note:

1. I have **not been able to** have **two views of one file** unless you save the first to a different name and reopen as per the example that you link to.
2. It is **confusing** that `Split Horizontally` and `Vertically` seem to be the opposite of intended like it is a **STATUS** indicator and toggle AFTER you move one file to the other view
3. Try `Read-Only` on one file to avoid editing the wrong file accidentally.

#### Further related tex stackechange instructions

- [Dual sessions/instances](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473233/170109)
- [Split viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471069/170109)
- [Split editor and viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472806/170109)