# Splitting the same text in two windows with Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, emacs

How is it possible to split the **same text** in two windows with TeXstudio, like it is done here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364455/89734.

I like very much TeXstudio since a friend introduced me to it. This editor has really amazing features. But I miss this emacs feature: it enables e.g. to copy a part of a text and to paste it in another part (like a complicated formula) without having to scroll the text.

Comment: A user asks to to get an Emacs feature in another editor. If the other editor would have been vim, ok. But Texstudio? Just keep using Emacs.

Comment: @Johannes_B That's really a useless comment. Because 1) TeXstudio has a lot of features that emacs does not have, 2) it is possible, see the picture. Unfortunately, the author of the post does not answer my question I posted 2 days ago.

Comment: I don't think TeXstudio can do this. See [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/584/) open feature request.

Comment: It's possible that the image you refer to is actually of two separate, but seemingly identical, files.

Comment: @Circumscribe I'll take your comment as the answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes indeed. I can already display two text files side-by-side; as a workaround, one possibility would be to write a script copying the file I am editing in another one which would be being edited at the same time, I'd just have to refresh the other window... I'll post something if I come up with something interesting. Because it's a really useful feature for large text file.

Comment: I've found a workaround actually ! I keep using TeXstudio and I open the text file also with _gedit_ (I use Ubuntu). Every time the text file is changed, if I go to the _gedit_ window, _gedit_ warns me and asks me to reload the text.

Comment: You may wish to give due consideration to alzi's answer.  The hard-link approach he describes is a great way to accomplish this, for any editor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can do it by opening a second window (instance) of TexStudio with the same .tex file. To do this, you need to follow [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/start-texstudio-portable-in-multiple-instances).

Comment: Yes it works ! Under Ubuntu, change in `/usr/share/applications/texstudio.desktop` the line `Exec=texstudio %F` to `Exec=texstudio --start-always %F`. I mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think TeXstudio can do this.

You can find an open [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/584/) for this on the TeXstudio SourceForge page. 
In the discussion below this request one of the developers of TeXstudio indcates that this feature is unlikely to be implemented in the near future:

> **Tim Hoffmann — 2017-05-09**
>
> No changes. This is not possible with the current editor component and
>   it doesn't look like there'll be an alternative. So as of now, there
>   is no indication that this request can be fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by adding a hard link in the file system and use the original file in the first view and the hardlinked file in the second view of the splitted editor window.

In detail...

To add a hardlink in NTFS filesystem you need to start cmd with administrator rights by pressing the WIN key, typing cmd, clicking "run as administrator". Lets assume your document is called `document.tex`. Then type:

```
mklink /H documentlink.tex document.tex
```

This will generate a hard link called `documentlink.tex`. This link behaves like a normal file.

Working with LUNIX the command:

```
ln document.tex documentlink.tex
```

should do the job.

So in the end you have two files `document.tex` and `documentlink.tex` pointing to the same data on hard-disk. This means when you edit (and save) one of the files the other one is also modified the same way.

Now you can load `document.tex` and `documentlink.tex` in the editor and move the `documentlink.tex` to the other view. Then change the data in `document.tex`. When you try to edit `documentlink.tex` you will be notified once that the file has changed.

It is possible to view different positions and copy and paste text between these files. When you save or compile one file, the other one is updated automatically.

I use this work around at the moment and it works very well for me, since my texfile has grown quite large.

Please use this settings in TexStudio:

Options menu
Configuration
Show Advanced Options
Adv. Editor
(uncheck) Safe writing of files
(check) Monitor open files for external changes
(check) Silently reload saved files on external changes

`Safe writing to files` will overwrite the hardlink since the programm saves to a temporary file and copies it to the file named in the editor. So it has to be deactivated.

When you work with Linux then load the original file first, then the hardlink. Move the hardlink to the second view and mark this tab as `read only`. Only edit and save the first tab. Now it works also under Linux :)

---

Here's a reference Steven pointed to: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/131182-create-soft-hard-symbolic-links-windows.html#option3

Because hard links are handled at the OS level, the technique works for any editor (confirmed [by Steven] for TeXworks).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you add an screenshot and explain a little bit better what one has to do to get the wished result ...

Comment: That does not work for me. By hard link, you mean ln file1 file2 ?

Comment: Works for me in a Windows system.  This is great!  And because it is handled at the OS level, the technique works for any editor.  Thank you!  Here is a Win reference: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/131182-create-soft-hard-symbolic-links-windows.html#option3. Perhaps you might want to edit your answer and list this (or other) links.

Comment: Also, I am able to do this without running as administrator.  Can you think of any reason why doing so would be a problem?

Comment: I am happy for Windows users. Unfortunately, this workaround does not work for linux.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher While I do not use Linux myself, I did find this webpage that talks of hard links: https://linuxhandbook.com/hard-link/