# How to open multiple instances of TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

Normally, we can open a second window (instance) of TexStudio with the same `.tex` file by changing the file association for `.tex` files to include `--start-always` (see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/start-texstudio-portable-in-multiple-instances)).

However, after installing the most recent version of TexStudio (4.6.3) on windows 10, I find that setting `"c:\path\to\texstudio.exe" --start-always "%1"` is no longer working. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm also using Windows 10 and TeXstudio 4.6.3. The `--start-always` option works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. The key is that you have to click on the icon of the tex file (to be opened) in order to open a second window of TexStudio, not the icon of TexStudio on the desktop.